# Simplify declarations in Angular

Tags: angular

Before with Angular 2, I was able to import/export my components with that :

```
import * as containersComponent from './containers'
import * as uiComponent from './ui'
import * as allDirectives from './directives'

export function mapValuesToArray(obj){ return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]) }
export const containers = [...mapValuesToArray(containersComponent)]
export const ui = [...mapValuesToArray(uiComponent)]
export const directives = [...mapValuesToArray(allDirectives)]
```

Then I declared them like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, containers, ui, directives ],
   ...
})
```

Now, since I moved to Angular 4 I get this error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function
```

Could someone help me please?

**EDIT to meet the demand for more details of andrei-macarie**

The error I receive refers to the call to `mapValuesToArray(obj)`. Angular 4 doesn't accept that I call a function like this. 
Even if I move the function in another way, for example if I call the `Object.Key(obj)` function directly in the const, I have the same error.

To illustrate, this function worked in Angular 2 for the providers :

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers:    [
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: (config: LanguagesService) => () => config.load(),
          deps: [LanguagesService],
          multi: true
        }]
    ...
})
```

In Angular 4, I get the same error that the log I post on the top, but for the call of config.load.
To avoid that, I made this :

```
export function languagesLoader(config: LanguagesService) {
  return () => config.load()
}

@NgModule({
  providers:    [
    ...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: languagesLoader,
      deps: [LanguagesService],
      multi: true
    }]
    ...
})
```

I tried to do it for my current problem, it doesn't work. So, my problem is how to call functions like this for declarations ? But also, maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: where are you calling the mapValuesToArray() function in the providers?

Comment: I think you should check the modules (./containers, ./ui, ./directives) to see if there are exports which are not components. If you missed one then things might crumble.

Comment: There's no call to mapValuesToArray() in the providers, it was just to show you that the problem doesn't come from the function itself but from how it's call. There's no problem either in ./container, ./ui and ./directives, it works if I call them manually in a const to simulate the function.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work as the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html) states:

```
interface NgModule {
providers : Provider[]
declarations : Array<Type<any>|any[]>
imports : Array<Type<any>|ModuleWithProviders|any[]>
exports : Array<Type<any>|any[]>
entryComponents : Array<Type<any>|any[]>
bootstrap : Array<Type<any>|any[]>
schemas : Array<SchemaMetadata|any[]>
id : string
}
```

Also looking through the changelog found nothing but noticed they are flattening the array inside this [code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.x/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts).

You can also flatten and dedupe the array yourself by using their code and see if that works:

```
function flattenArray(tree: any[], out: Array<any> = []): Array<any> {
  if (tree) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
      const item = resolveForwardRef(tree[i]);
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        flattenArray(item, out);
      } else {
        out.push(item);
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}

function dedupeArray(array: any[]): Array<any> {
  if (array) {
    return Array.from(new Set(array));
  }
  return [];
}

function flattenAndDedupeArray(tree: any[]): Array<any> {
  return dedupeArray(flattenArray(tree));
}
```

So just call `flattenAndDedupeArray(yourDeclarations)`.

**NOTE:** Instead of using `mapValuesToArray(obj)` you can do just `Object.values(obj)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's not the function itself that doesn't work but how it is called. It seems that in Angular 4 we can't call static functions anywhere. If I could find another way to called this function, in a way that is allowed in Angular 4, it would work.

Comment: Can you explain a bit which static function are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, I try to be more comprehensible in the edit of my original post.